# React app served by express server not importing resoruces

Tags: reactjs, express

I am trying to serve a react app that i built and my js and css are not imported. I get a 404 code. Here is the routing code and the file system that I am using. Can someone help me. I don't know where am I messing up.
I am trying to serve the index.html inside the public folder.

**Code:**

```
app.use( express.static( path.join( __dirname, `../pubilc` ) ) );
app.use( express.json( { limit: '1mb' } ) );
app.use( express.urlencoded( { limit: '30mb', extended: true } ) );
app.use( '/usr', userRouter );
app.use( '/planifications', planificationRouter );


app.get( '/', ( _req: Request, res: Response ) => {
    res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname, '../public', 'index.html' ) );
} );
```

**FileSystem:**
[image]

Comment: You have a typo in your first line of code: The directory is called 'public':  path.join( __dirname, `../public` )

Comment: wow! Thanks! I feel so awfull now :(